# How to remove white space between slider and navigation?

Tags: css, layout

how to remove white space between slider and navigation? Can't find the css tag to remove the white space. Thanks

Here's the CSS of slider:

```
 #slider-banner {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #111;
```

Navigation

```
 .main-navigation {
clear: both;
display: block;
font-weight: 300;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
position: relative;
border-bottom: 3px solid #04A3ED;
background: #00ABFF;
```

Here's the [site](http://goo.gl/u7o6hS)

Comment: could be margin or padding properties. Could you please provide some css/code?

Comment: have you the relevant html too? but i think it *could* be to do with your `position` being `relative`?

Comment: Could you write about which 'white space' you are talking about? And what is the expected result? For now I can only guess: try adding `height: 400px` for `div.slides`.

Comment: @damgad i already talk about white space, pls read the question again. Not working

Comment: There is no space between your slider and navigation.

Comment: You need to fix the images in your slider. it is the height of your images that make it look broken

Comment: I see. I will adjust the height of the images. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. I used `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` from jQuery to split my navigation bar.
It looks like both of them had `margin-bottom: 10px;` by default in CSS. So, change it in your own css to 0px so it will override jQuery.